# Convert *.md file to *.docx by right click using Pandoc

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, context-menu, markdown, pandoc

I would like to be able to easily generate *.docx files from *.md ones by just right-clicking on the file and selecting "Convert to docx". I used to do this manually by using Pandoc in the Windows command prompt but it is becoming a little bit repetitive and wish to make it more user friendly. What procedure would you apply to achieve such result?

Comment: [How to Add Any Application Shortcut to Windows Explorer’s Context Menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/)

Comment: Also check out these questions: [Posts containing 'windows add to file context menu' - Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=windows+add+to+file+context+menu)